# DataGrid Placeholder Row Header customization

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datagridrowheader

I have a WPF DataGrid, the DataSource is an `ObservableCollection<MyItem>`

`MyItem` has property called `Hour`, which is automatically generated. Hour is used as a RowHeader in the DataGrid.

If I add a new item to the collection, the Hour property is filled and the RowHeader will display it. But I have no control over the RowHeader of the "placeholder row".

How can I achieve that the RowHeader of the placeholder row is always a `*` character, but all the normal rows have the `Hour` property as a RowHeader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed hour from `MyItem` (not really needed there), and made RowHeader to be auto-generated.
If Row.Item is not a MyItem then the `*` gets set to Row.Header programatically.

```
    void DataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.Item is MyItem)
        {
            e.Row.Header = (e.Row.GetIndex()).ToString("D2");
        }
        else // Row is {NewItemPlaceholder}
        {
            e.Row.Header = "✲";
        }
    }
```